# How can I compare two values in kdb/Q and output a message based on pass/fail?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, kdb

I'm trying to build my own unit testing framework in Q, and what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
// Is the expected value (EQUAL_TO/GREATER_THAN/LESS_THAN/ETC) the actual value?
// Object Object Object -> String
// checkExpect[5; =; 2+3] -> "Pass"
// checkExpect[1; =; 2+3] -> "Fail"
```

The function takes in 3 arguments, the expected output, the operator ('=', '>', etc.), and the actual value, such as a function or expression.

I'm having trouble piecing those 3 together, and on top of that outputting either a "Pass" or "Fail" statement to see if the entire function passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `x` and `z` as arguments to `y`

The result boolean `0b` and `1b` can be used to index in to a list to choose either `Pass` or `Fail`

```
q)checkExpect:{("Fail";"Pass") y[x;z]}
q)checkExpect[5; =; 2+3]
"Pass"
q)checkExpect[1; =; 2+3]
"Fail"
```

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/function-notation/

`x` `y` `z` are special arguments you can skip naming

`{[x;y;z] x+y+z}` is the same as `{x+y+z}`

You might define your function with chosen names for clarity instead:

```
checkExpect:{[a;test;b] ("Fail";"Pass") test[a;b]}
```

Comment: Wow yes that works great! I'm still new to kdb/Q, I thought variables had to be one of the first things named in the braces? The language is a bit confusing to me right now but there seems to be a lot of ways to write a function.

Comment: I updated the answer to explain that `x` `y` `z` are special names you can use for short functions without naming them inside `[]`.